# PSTreeGraph - Don't draw line between root and first child when build large treeview in Ipad Retina

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Can you help me. 
I use PSTreeGraph (https://github.com/epreston/PSTreeGraph/). 
It doesn't draw line between root and first child when build large treeview in Ipad Retina

![PSTreeGraph][1]
https://github.com/epreston/PSTreeGraph/issues/27

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, in PSBaseBranchView.m add code `CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer`.

```
[[treeGraph connectingLineColor] set];
[path setLineWidth:[treeGraph connectingLineWidth]];

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.lineWidth = [treeGraph connectingLineWidth];

[self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
//[path stroke];
```